# Hook when async method is started

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

Is there an integration point into the async/await mechanisms to hook in and know when an async method is started?

Can a custom TaskScheduler provide this hook?  A custom SynchronizationContext?

I want to be able to track certain method calls and know which Task (or code) they're associated with.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What kind of record-keeping are you talking about? What have you tried?

Comment: The method starts as soon as you call it. It's really unclear what you mean...

Comment: I want a place in code where I can be notified that an async method has been started without having to modify the call site or the callee.

Comment: `TaskScheduler` can do this, mostly. I can think of 2 problems off the top of my head: 1) It would be hard to match the `Task` instances with the `async` methods (and their continuations). 2) Any `async` method can jump out of your `TaskScheduler` by using `ConfigureAwait`. The only sure-fire solution is to use the profiling API, and that would be difficult (and you'd still have to solve problem (1) somehow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) in section "Task Status":

> All tasks returned from TAP methods must be “hot” [...] meaning that the asynchronous operations they represent have already been initiated and their TaskStatus is an enumeration value other than Created.

That means that you will always start the `Task` as soon as you create it (at least if the factory method implements the TAP, which is true for all methods provided by the .Net framework).

If you create and return a "cold" (non-running) `Task` using `new Task()`, there is no clean way to find out if the `Task.Start()` method was called. You can only check the `TaskStatus` property periodically.

Comment: Thanks, PeterB!  That's good information.  These Tasks are all "hot" and I don't need to know *if* they are started (because they are certainly started) but when any otherwise unknown task is started (detected *of* user code *by* an initialized library)

Comment: Sorry to get you wrong there. As stephen Cleary mentioned, you can try providing a `TaskScheduler` that overloads `TryDequeue`. In addition to the problems he mentioned, you should also consider, that the basic idea of the TAP is, that resource management is hidden. TAP methods might not even use Tasks, but Threads, Events or synchronous code inside. TAP methods might also return void instead of a Task.